# How to list all variables defined by myself in Python, excluding imported variables?

Tags: python, variables

I know there are some ways to list all variable, such as locals(), globals(), dir(). But they also list the variables imported from other modules, and make a very long list, which is hard to find variables defined by myself. So how should I list all variables defined by myself, better with their values?

Here is an example:

```
import numpy
a=1
b=2
dir()
```

Then the result is:

```
['In',
 'Out',
 '_',
 '_1',
 '_2',
 '_3',
 '_4',
 '__',
 '___',
 '__builtin__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '_dh',
 '_i',
 '_i1',
 '_i2',
 '_i3',
 '_i4',
 '_i5',
 '_ih',
 '_ii',
 '_iii',
 '_oh',
 '_sh',
 'a',
 'b',
 'exit',
 'get_ipython',
 'numpy',
 'quit']
```

But I only want to see variables defined in this module, i.e., a and b. How should I do that?

Comment: You wrote the code.  Why do you not know what you imported?

Comment: If you want values, then log them. If you're not willing to do that, then why not just use a debugger with a carefully placed breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Save the result of `locals()` at the top of your module, after any imports.

Any new items that subsequently show up in `locals()` must have been defined by you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as you can see in my added example, remembering all variables in imported module seems unrealistic. Maybe I can use a variable to record the result of locals() after importing, but it is a little troublesome to do that.

Comment: `my_vars = [v for v in locals() if v not in original_locals]`